# Filtering through page by dropdown filter

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

**Dropdown**

[image]

I am few weeks into learning rails, react and js. I apologies in advance if my question or answer is real easy. 
I want to filter through the page by using the dropdown filter bar. I have provided the image. I have provided my code below. This code is in rails app. Thanks in advance!

```
<div class="row data-query">
<div class="col-xs-3 filterby">Filter By</div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 filter">
    <ul class="filter-dropdown pull-left">
      <li class="dropdown" value="all">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Condition <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="FilterContainer">
          <li><a href="#">Like New</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Good Condition</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Fair Condition</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><%= link_to "", toys_path %></li>

        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 filter">
    <ul class="filter-dropdown pull-left">
      <li class="dropdown" value="all">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Age Group <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="FilterContainer">
          <li><a href="#">0-1yr</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">1-2yrs</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2-4yrs</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">4-8yrs</a></li>
          <li><%= link_to "", toys_path %></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 filter">
    <ul class="filter-dropdown pull-left">
      <li class="dropdown" value="all">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Category <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="FilterContainer">
          <li><a href="#">Activity & Learning</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Arts & Crafts</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Baby Toys</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Dolls</a></li>
          <li><%= link_to "", toys_path %></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
$('select').change(function () {
var current = this.value;

if (current == 'all') {
    $('#FilterContainer').find('li.all').show();
} else {

    $('#FilterContainer').find('li').hide();
    $('#FilterContainer').find('li.all.' + current).show();
}

return false;
```

});

Answer (score 0):

That type of search is easy to do in Rails with the help of the Ransack gem. https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack

In your view you will have something like this, depending on your Model:

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
    <div>
        <%= f.label :condition %>
        <%= f.collection_select :condition, Condition.all, :id, :name, {include_blank: "All Conditions"} %>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%= f.submit "Search" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```